# How to implement html chart in vaadin?

Tags: html, css, vaadin

I have used this code in vaadin html file. But output is nothing.

Code refrence: https://vaadin.com/charts-for-polymer

Please let me know how to correct and implement in my vaadin design.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webcomponentsjs/0.7.21/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="https://cdn.vaadin.com/vaadin-charts/3.0.0-alpha9/vaadin-

charts.html">
</head>
<body>
<template is="dom-bind" id="app">
  <vaadin-pie-chart id="pie-with-legend">
    <title>Revenue by industry</title>
    <subtitle>2015</subtitle>
    <tooltip point-format="<b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>">
    </tooltip>
    <plot-options>
      <pie allow-point-select="true" show-in-legend="true"cursor="pointer">
        <data-labels enabled="true"format="{point.name}: {point.y:.1f} M€"></data-labels>
      </pie>
    </plot-options>
    <data-series name="Revenue" data="[[seriesData]]"></data-series>
  </vaadin-pie-chart>
  <my-data-source data="{{seriesData}}"></my-data-source>
</template>
<dom-module id="my-data-source">
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "my-data-source",
      properties: {
        data: {
          type: Array,
          notify: true,
          value: [
            ["Aerospace", 53.0],
            ["Medical", 53.6],
            ["Agriculture", 25.6],
            ["Automotive", 17.0],
            ["Consumers", 12.4],
            ["Subsidies", 1.4]]
        }
    }});
  </script>
</dom-module>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems to be working just fine in http://jsbin.com/lebuqo/edit?html,output ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly in chrome, yet it fails on firefox 
(console: Polymer not defined).

What you need to do is, wrap the polymer code in a check like:

```
addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
    Polymer({
      is: "my-data-source",
      ....
```

see working example here: https://jsbin.com/tifafepefi/edit?html,output